# is it possible to print an html content on button click without any preview or selection?

Tags: javascript, printing, skip, print-preview

My requirement is to directly print an invoice whenever the submit button is clicked. since there are too many invoices in the whole day, and it would take time to always click print and time is money as they said :/, this is my js code, and it works fine to print a div with its content. but how to directly print it without getting to the print preview dialog?

JS CODE

```
$scope.printFactureClient=function(){
        var printContents = document.getElementById('printFacture').innerHTML;
        var popupWin = window.open('Facture Clinet', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../design/mainPage.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
        popupWin.document.close();


    }
```

Or this should be handled from the browser? my client browser is chrome installed on windows 10. appreciate any help! its stopping my work flow

Comment: Either a print server or build some browser plugin probably.

Comment: It takes only a few dozen milliseconds to press [Enter] after clicking a button, how much time can be saved from that anyway? Besides, without Print Preview, it's possible there's a different company printer the job needs to go to, etc. You can't make any of those assumptions from the browser's perspective.

Comment: yea and i can setTimeout to close the window after 1.5 sec, so all what he need to do is clicking ENTER. i'll try this with them, hopefully they will accept this as a solution, otherwise i have to go to the server way

Comment: @PatrickRoberts bypassing the print dialog is a use-case often encountered in kiosk or point-of-sales applications (think receipt printing after POS transactions, or a kiosk overriding a print dialog in order to maintain a consistent UI/UX with the embedded kiosk application). The printing environment in Chrome can be queried using the `printerProvider` extension API.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have full freedom to implement `windows.print()` however they want.

Unfortunately, Chrome has not exposed any sort of API to manipulate the print dialog. However, if you have control over the Chrome execution environment, (that is you can control how Chrome is started, i.e. change its command line arguments by shortcut), you can run `chrome.exe` with the `--args --disable-print-preview` command line arguments. Every other solution is even hackier (sending data via `nativeMessaging` extension API to a .NET application that instantiates `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument`, for example).

FireFox has a browser config override called `print.always_print_silent` that won't pop the print dialog when printing via Firefox extension.

Comment: I tried to add this `--args --disable-print-preview` in the shortcut properties but it rejected saying the name is invalid, what i did is: 
right click on the chrome shortcut > properties, in the properties tab > Target Box, add the `--args --disable-print-preview` and it finaly looks like this:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --args --disable-print-preview` i also tried to only add this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-print-preview` but also not working and the same error popup saying the name is invalid

Answer (score 0):

You need a server to send the data to the browser as a response. Browsers do not allow for printing without going through a print preview first. The only way to bypass that is by a server response which would involve writing the response method of that server to return a byte stream that would automatically download on the client.

This article is a quick and simplistic tutorial of how to do that using .NET servers: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/afenster/how-to-download-a-file-in-Asp-Net/

Of course you could do this in just about any language/server.